# Can't figure out how to download the proper libraries or begin using beautifulsoup for python web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

absolute beginner using pycharm and python 3.8, want to start webscraping but I haven't understood any tutorials on how to actually get all the prerequisites for using beautifulsoup.

Do i use the built in terminal in pycharm? do i use my mac's terminal, do i use pycharm's project interpreter? Just overall confused on the whole process of starting web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Install Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)
2. [Quick Start](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)